# how to determine attachment order in email MIME format

Tags: java, email, email-attachments, mime

I'm using `MimeMessageParser` in Java to parse emails in MIME format. When I get the attachments, the order doesn't seem correct. They are in the order in which they appear in the MIME file, but that's not the order in which they were attached.

Is there a way to determine the order of the attachments (based on which was attached first) when parsing the email?